# Contract for IConnectableObservable.Connect with regards to multiple calls

Tags: .net, system.reactive, observable

What is the contract supposed to be for IConnectableObservable.Connect when it's called more than once?

When the IDisposable returned is disposed of should OnCompleted be published or should it just disconnect and allow Connect to be called a second time?

If Connect is called a second time before the first is disposed of, should it:

- Throw
- Return the same IDisposable, possibly having an unexpected dispose from different regions of code
- Return a new IDisposable with some sort of Dispose reference counting and cause issues with a source you called Dispose on still publishing values

I'm trying to implement IConnectableObservable and the documentation for people implementing it is really light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/develop/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/ConnectableObservable.cs#L39-L77)

The answer to your first question (as of writing):

> When the IDisposable returned is disposed of should OnCompleted be published or should it just disconnect and allow Connect to be called a second time?

Just disconnects

> If Connect is called a second time before the first is disposed of

It should: Return the same IDisposable, possibly having an unexpected dispose from different regions of code

For posterity sake the interesting code sections are:

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            lock (_parent._gate)
            {
                if (_subscription != null)
                {
                    _subscription.Dispose();
                    _subscription = null;

                    _parent._connection = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
    public IDisposable Connect()
    {
        lock (_gate)
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                var subscription = _source.SubscribeSafe(_subject);
                _connection = new Connection(this, subscription);
            }

            return _connection;
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the above there is a single connection which is disposed and connected to within a lock block to prevent concurrent modification.

Comment: In general, I've found that it's a bad idea to trust any given implementation to be the "correct" interpretation of how the interface should be implemented unless it's called out as the reference implementation. Even in a library like Rx, the person doing the implementation might not be the same as the one who wrote the interface or they might not have thought about the specifics and just done what was convenient. In the absence of other documentation though I agree that it's probably the best reference to use.

Comment: @BryanAnderson I agree in principle that it can be problematic to trust a single source. In this case though, I would infer a higher level of confidence since .Net *is* the reference implementation for Rx, it is the oldest and most stable platform. That being said, at least two other implementation, RxJS and RxJava (which also means RxScala), use the same semantics. I can add that above if it would give you higher confidence in the answer.

Comment: I have an issue raised in their GitHub project asking for clarification as well. The Rx libraries have had interfaces and interface contracts change quite a few times since they were created so I'm not quite as trusting about unofficial implementation details as I would be with one of BCL implementations. I'll mark you answer as accepted if I don't hear anything by the weekend.